# undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass got this error while merging instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller i am merging the results of two different instance variables into one instance variable and i got an following error:

```
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my controller code

```
  @conversational = InterestType.where("institution_id = ? or global = ? and category_id = ?", current_user.profile.institution_id, true, 1).first

    @commercial = InterestType.where("institution_id = ? or global = ? and category_id = ?", current_user.profile.institution_id, true, 2).limit(17)

    @user_interest_types << @conversational

    @user_interest_types << @commercial
```

How can i get over of this error or what is the good way to get following result.

1. I want to display first conversational interest type then other 17 commercial interest types.

Comment: `@user_interest_types` must be `nil`. Check to make sure that you've initialized it before pushing objects onto it.

Comment: @user_interest_types = {}  like this?

Comment: No, `@user_interest_types = []`

Comment: @chs Do you want it to be an array or a hash? I assume you probably want an array so you would initialize like this `@user_interest_types = []`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to append to an array you have two options and here you must pay attention to what you're adding:

```
# Define an empty array
@user_interest_types = [ ]

# Add a single element to an array
@user_interest_types << @conversational

# Append an array to an array
@user_interest_types += @commercial
```

If you use `<<` for both operations you end up pushing an array *into* an array and the resulting structure has multiple layers. You can see this if you call `inspect` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nested array:

```
@user_interest_types = [@conversational, @commercial]

# gives [it1, [it2, it3, it4]]
```

Or if you prefer a flat array:

```
@user_interest_types = [@conversational, *@commercial]

# gives [it1, it2, it3, it4]
```

Assuming `@conversational = it1` and `@commercial = [it2, it3, it4]`